# Spring controller enum request validation

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a simple spring rest controller that looks like this.

```
@RestController
public class MyController {

@RequestMapping(path = "mapping", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = {"application/json"})
    public MyResponse create(@RequestBody MyModel requestParam
    ) throws InvalidApplicationSentException, AuthenticationFailedException {
 // method body
}
```

Here is the MyModel class that's used as a request parameter.

```
public class MyModel {
    private RequestType requestType;
    // a lot of other properties ..
}
```

Now when i try to call this endpoint passing an invalid value for RequestType I get back an exeption:

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException
Could not read document: Can not construct instance of com.mypackage.RequestType from String value 'UNDEFINED': value not one of declared Enum instance names: [IMPROTANT, NOT_IMPORTANT]
```

Is there a way that spring would set the enum to null when passed incorrect value and not throw an error?

I'm using spring 4 and I would prefer configuration with annotations and not xml files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to implement a custom JSON serialization method in your enum class
http://chrisjordan.ca/post/50865405944/custom-json-serialization-for-enums-using-jackson

Use `@JsonCreator` in your enum and on `null` or `undefined` value just return `null` to get going.

```
@JsonCreator
public static RequestType create(String value) {
    if(value == null) {
        return null;
    }
    for(RequestType v : values()) {
        if(value.equals(v.getName())) {
            return v;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```